Upgrading to Ubuntu 24 on wifi network
I am trying to upgrade my laptop to Ubuntu 24. The system fails saying this is an unsecure network. Not sure what the issue is. Can someone please help with network settings that seem to trigger this response? I have tried setting up a wired connection.However that connection seems to fail. I am unsure if that is due to some hardware issue or something related to drivers etc. I have been using a wifi connection on my laptop for ever. In fact I uploaded version 22 via wifi and that seemed to work fine. Appreciate your help. Thank You.
